# Chart.js with JSON data error

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, chart.js

Having a tough time trying to get this to work...

Required scripts

```
<script src="Chart.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
```

Full code of what I am trying to work with.

```
<body>
<div id="chartCanvas">
 <canvas id="StatusChart"></canvas>
 <br>
 </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$.ajax({url:"json.php",dataType:"json"})
  .fail(function(){alert("Doh! We have an error some where!")})
  .done(function(data){
  var myData = (data);
  console.log(myData[0].status);
Array.prototype.mapProperty = function(status) {
      return this.map(function (obj) {
       return obj[status];
      });

     };

 lineChartData = {
    labels : myData.mapProperty('status'),
     datasets : [
       {
   label: "My First dataset",
   fillColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
   strokeColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
   pointColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
   pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
   pointHighlightFill : "#fff",
   pointHighlightStroke : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
   data : myData.mapProperty('count')
  }
       ]
  };

 //window.onload = function(){
console.log("cheerio")
 var ctx = document.getElementById("StatusChart").getContext("3D");
 window.myLine = new Chart(ctx).Line(lineChartData);
 //}  

}); 

</script>
</body>
```

I have been successful on getting the JSON data to ouput in the following format.

[{"status":"Status_Name_Here","count":"1"}]

Upon load of the page I get an error.

In console everything seems to load correctly, then I get a "Use of Mutation Events is deprecated. Use MutationObserver instead."

Here is a copy & paste of console.

```
GET 
https://sitee.com/chart/ [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 191ms]
GET 
https://sitee.com/chart/Chart.js [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 50ms]
GET 
https://sitee.com/chart/jquery-1.11.3.min.js [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 98ms]
GET 
XHR 
https://sitee.com/chart/json.php [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 62ms]
Use of Mutation Events is deprecated. Use MutationObserver instead.
```

Anyone have any clue as to where I am going wrong?

Comment: Looks like the `json.php` files isn't being found *"404 Not Found"*.

Comment: lol Doh! It all blends together :(

Comment: I need to be done for the day.... I didnt upload JSON to the FTP LOL! wow. Ill delete the question

Comment: You have `.getContext("3D")` here, which doesn't exist (note there is `"webgl"`), do you mean `.getContext("2d")` since this is a line chart?

Comment: Made the adjustments and still nothing.

Comment: Do you still have `TypeError: context is null`? Are you sure the `canvas` is loaded before the `script` is ran?

Comment: GET 
https://sitee.com/chart/ [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 287ms]
GET 
https://siteecom/chart/Chart.js [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 48ms]
GET 
https://sitee.com/chart/jquery-1.11.3.min.js [HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified 98ms]
Use of Mutation Events is deprecated. Use MutationObserver instead. kwift.FFJETPACK.min.js:1564:0

Comment: That is what I am getting now.

Comment: okay, so I have been able to populate the canvas, but now my data is "undefined". I am trying to count the status

Comment: That is just a warning message, it looks like `lineChartData` is being defined in an asynchronous call, meaning it's not yet defined/set when you attempt to draw it afterwards. Try adding the chart directly in the `.done()` function.

Comment: added a comment right above your last post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix your JSON

```
$query = " SELECT column_name,COUNT(*) FROM tablename GROUP BY column_name;  ";

            $result = mysql_query( $query );
                if ( !$result ) {
                    $ErrorMessage  = 'Invalid query: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";
                    $ErrorMessage .= 'Whole query: ' . $query;
                die( $ErrorMessage );
        }

        $JSON_output = array();
            while ( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc( $result ) )
        {

        $JSON_output[] = array('ItemToCount'        => $row['ItemToCount'], 
                                'count'         => $row['COUNT(*)'],
                            );
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue. Appreciate the help for pointing out the few mistakes :) . @spencer wieczorek

Required scripts

```
<script src="Chart.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
```

Code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.ajax({url:"json.php",dataType:"json"})
  .fail(function(){alert("Im a failure")})
  .done(function(data){
  var myData = (data);
  console.log(myData[0].kpi);
Array.prototype.mapProperty = function(property) {
      return this.map(function (obj) {
       return obj[property];
      });

     };

// Example: myData.mapProperty('rank') to get an array of all ranks 
 lineChartData = {
    labels : myData.mapProperty('column_name'),
     datasets : [
       {
   label: "Data",
   fillColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
   strokeColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
   pointColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
   pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
   pointHighlightFill : "#fff",
   data : myData.mapProperty('count')
  }
       ]
  };

 //window.onload = function(){
console.log("cheerio")
 var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
 window.myLine = new Chart(ctx).Line(lineChartData);
 //}  

}); </script>
```